# How to create an agreement pop-up on blogger?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I'm wondering how to create a `pop-up` agreement when someone visits my blog.

I tried some `pop-ups` using JavaScript but none of them work.

Actually I want the visitor to agree with my terms and conditions when they visit my blog.

Comment: It's always useful to explain (with code if possible) what you have tried already. This helps others to answer your question more quickly and properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var hasAgreed = confirm("Do you agree my terms and condition?");
```

If the user accepts, `hasAgreed` will have `true` else `false`

Put that in `onload` event of your page and then store the response in a cookie and don't ask them next time by doing a simple `if`.